# What system calls does one use for sending data over the internet?

Tags: linux, networking

Seeing as network interfaces don't have a location within `/dev`, I'm curious as to how one would program utilities that make web requests (or configure stuff), i.e

```
ip link set *interface* up
iw dev *interface* scan
```

Specifically, what system calls would one even use?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

`strace -e trace=network ip link 2>log2.txt`

then read `log2.txt` to see what system calls were made by `ip link`. From there you can search the web or man pages for more specific details.